# Two UIAlertView

Tags: xcode6, uialertview

I have two UIAlertview ,i want to go to different page when i click inside,i create two xib file,and import them in main Viewcontroller,but don't know why can't show it,that is nothing wrong flag when i check~
Here is my code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LP01;" message:@"No Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Help", nil];


UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LP01;" message:@"No Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Help", nil];




- (void)alert:(UIAlertView *)alertview clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {


            if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        AViewController *switch1 = [[AViewController alloc]
                                   initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:switch1 animated:YES completion:NULL];

            }
}

- (void)alert1:(UIAlertView *)alertview clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {



    if (buttonIndex == 1) {


        BViewController *switch2 = [[BViewController alloc]
                                    initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:switch2 animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
}
```

Please Help and Thanks~

Comment: Did this question is solved now ??

Comment: still didn't solved yet~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *firstAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LP01;" message:@"No Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Help", nil];


UIAlertView *secondAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"LP01;" message:@"No Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Help", nil];
```

// Remember Delegate methods will be same for any number of elements related to it. So whether you have 2 or 3 or 5 UIAlertView's you delegate method will be written only once.

```
- (void)alert:(UIAlertView *)alertview clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(alertview == firstAlert){



            AViewController *switch1 = [[AViewController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            [self presentViewController:switch1 animated:YES completion:NULL];


    }
    else if(alertview == secondAlert){



            BViewController *switch2 = [[BViewController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            [self presentViewController:switch2 animated:YES completion:NULL];


    }
}
```

// Don't forget to call [firstAlert show]; or [secondAlert show]; to show your alert